# Shared folders in Ubuntu 20.04 Guest in Windows 10 Host Virtualbox not working

Tags: virtualbox, 20.04

I have followed the same steps that I used for an Ubuntu 18.04 Guest VM but the expected icon for `sf_Sharedfolder` does not appear on the desktop of the Ubuntu20.04 guest VM. How do I proceed?

Comment: Is the Ubuntu user in the vboxsf group?

Comment: I have added the user to the vboxsf group and fully rebooted but the icon still does not appear. Are there any other changes I need to make?

Comment: Did you either log out/in the user in the VM, or reboot the VM? Group mods require this. And it might not be a desktop icon, but a selection in the left pane of Nautilus (Files).

Comment: SOLVED There is an entry in Nautilus for sf_SharedFolder which is what I was missing.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the comments...

In the Ubuntu VM...

- add the user to the vboxsf group
- log the user out, then back in, or reboot the VM
- open Nautilus (Files) and look for sf_SharedFolder in the left pane
- click on sf_SharedFolder to see the enclosed files